# Do I need to reveal a face-down card if it is put on top of my library?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a face-down card (such as a morph or manifested card), and an effect puts it on top of my library, do I need to reveal the card (as I would if it was destroyed or exiled)?

Example:

I attack my opponent with a manifest creature, and they cast [Whisk Away](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whisk%20Away) to put it on top of my library, do they get to know what the card put on top of my library is?

Comment: *"Do I need to reveal a face-down **permanent** if it **leaves the battlefield**?"* My suggested title edits are in bold. The latter is might be taking it too far, so I thought I would ask first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, you must reveal all face-down cards as they move zones or when you leave the game.**

> 707.9. If a face-down permanent moves from the battlefield to any other zone, its owner must reveal it to all players as he or she moves it. If a face-down spell moves from the stack to any zone other than the battlefield, its owner must reveal it to all players as he or she moves it. If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents and spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players. At the end of each game, all face-down permanents and spells must be revealed to all players.

The other players must be able to check that you were able to cast those cards face-down. Making an exception for manifested cards (which are not required to have the morph ability or any other property) would needlessly complicate the rule, and if you have both manifested and morphed creatures on the battlefield, it might be obscured which was which, again making room for error or even cheating.

Comment: The reasoning of checking that it was legal doesn't really apply to manifest. Manifest creatures are not cast face-down, they are put in play face-down by another effect (and can be anything).

Comment: It's true that the original reasoning is no longer always relevant, but that's still the rule, and it doesn't [change in Fate Reforged](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/fate-reforged-update-bulletin-comprehensive-rule-changes-2015-01-15)

Comment: @bengoesboom, It's better to keep the rule simple than to carve out an exception for Manifest.

Comment: Also, there could always be effects in the future that allow you to bring into play any non-Morph card face down as long as it has a certain property. For example: "T: put a creature card from your hand into play face-down. [etc]", only that the opponent doesn't know which creature it was.

Comment: @Hackworth - You mean like Illusionary Mask?